# How to disable removeViewBox plugin in Next.Js and svgr?

Tags: svg, webpack, next.js

I would like to disable the removeViewBox plugin in Next.js/svgr/svgo. The following next.config.js should work but it does not.
Anybody can help ?
I'm using it with:
"@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.0",  "react": "17.0.2", "next": "^12.0.7",

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n,
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: '@svgr/webpack',
            options: {
              prettier: false,
              svgo: true,
              icon: true,
              svgoConfig: {
                plugins: [
                  {
                    name: 'preset-default',
                    params: {
                      overrides: {
                        removeViewBox: false,
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
              titleProp: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      })
    return config
  },
}
```

Comment: There are some pretty obvious syntax errors in your config.  Fix those and test your code.

Answer (score 5):

This is what's worked for my with **`next@13.0.5`** and **`@svgr/webpack@6.5.1`**

```
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.svg$/i,
  issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
  use: [{ loader: '@svgr/webpack', options: { icon: true } }]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For `@svgr/webpack@5.5.0` it worked when I added `{ removeViewBox: false }` right to `plugins` array:

```js
{
  loader: '@svgr/webpack',
  options: {
    svgoConfig: {
      plugins: [
        { removeViewBox: false },
      ],
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: This seemed to work locally but fails in Vercel builds with `Error: Plugin name should be specified`. Not sure if it's a version conflict, or what.

Answer (score 0):

For `"@svgr/webpack": "^8.1.0"` the svgoConfig is changed - below config worked for me (*as mentioned in [SVGO GitHub repo](https://github.com/svg/svgo?tab=readme-ov-file#default-preset)*):

```js
plugins: [
    {
        name: 'preset-default',
        params: {
        overrides: {
            // disable a default plugin
            removeViewBox: false,

        //   // customize the params of a default plugin
        //   inlineStyles: {
        //     onlyMatchedOnce: false,
        //   },
        },
        },
    },
    ],
},
```